# Is it enough just to install LAMP?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, security, lamp

I use yum to install LAMP on Centos, like this:

```
yum install httpd mysql mysql-server php php-mysql

chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on

chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on

service httpd start

service mysqld start
```

Is it enough? Do I need to add security or something to it? Thank you very much.

**Edit:** Yes, it's going to be a website which will be accessible for everyone.

Comment: Is it enough for what?

Comment: @Flimzy: website

Comment: Clearly you intend it for a web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it enough?

No

> Do I need to add security or something to it?

Yes.

And not just security, but also log file management, monitoring, and other system administration staples of that ilk.

For example, is that mysql instance available over the public network interface?  Did you set a password for the root mysql user during the install?  Is there a firewall in place?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to put this machine online, then definitely you should be adding some firewall rules, recording your passwords, setting up MySQL security, thinking about doing regular package updates, etc. It all depends on how you plan to use it.